# $M \longmapsto M^3 + M$ bijective for real symmetric matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

> $\begin{array}{ccccc}
> f & : & S_n{\mathbb{(R)}} & \to & S_n\mathbb{(R)} \\
>  & & M & \mapsto & M^3+M \\
> \end{array}\,\,$
> prove that $f$ is a bijection

proof of surjectivity

let $A\in S_n{\mathbb{(R)}}.$ $\,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ its eigenvalues. There exists $Q$ an real orthogonal matrix such as $A =Q^\top \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \alpha_{n}\end{bmatrix} Q$
Let $ i \in [\![1,n]\!]$ there exists $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}$ such as $\alpha_i = \lambda_i^3 + \lambda_i$ (surjectivity of $x \longmapsto x^3 + x$ for real numbers)

let's define $B:= Q^\top \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \lambda_{n}\end{bmatrix} Q\,\,$ We have clearly $B\in S_n{\mathbb(R)}$ and $f(B) =A$

and I stuck for the injectivity

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383063/81360): the same map is surjective (but not injective) as a map over $M_n(\Bbb C)$

Comment: One approach: begin by noting that $M$ and $M^3 + M$ commute, which means that they must be simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: What about $n=1$?

Answer (score 1):

The function $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = x^3+x$ is a continuous bijection so there exists a continuous inverse $g^{-1} : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$.

Now notice that your function $f$ can be understood as $A \mapsto g(A)$ in the sense of [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) since the spectrum of $A$ is real. It makes sense to consider $A \mapsto g^{-1}(A) : S_n(\Bbb{R}) \to S_n(\Bbb{R})$ as well and we have
$$g^{-1}(g(A)) = (g^{-1}\circ g)(A) = \text{id}_{\sigma(A)}(A) = A, \quad g(g^{-1}(A)) = (g\circ g^{-1})(A) = \text{id}_{\sigma(A)}(A) = A$$
so this is in fact the inverse of $f$.